# How to cluster sentences by using n-gram overlap in Python?

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram

I need to cluster sentences according to common n-grams they contain. I am able to extract n-grams easily with nltk but I have no idea how to perform clustering based on n-gram overlap. That is why I couldn't write such a real code, first of all I am sorry for it. I wrote 6 simple sentences and expected output to illustrate the problem.

```
import nltk

Sentences= """I would like to eat pizza with her.
She would like to eat pizza with olive.
There are some sentences must be clustered.
These sentences must be clustered according to common trigrams.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Apples are red, bananas are yellow."""

sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/'+'English'+'.pickle')
sentence_tokens = sent_detector.tokenize(sentences.strip())

mytrigrams=[]
for sentence in sentence_tokens:
    trigrams=ngrams(sentence.lower().split(), 3)
    mytrigrams.append(list(trigrams))
```

After this I have no idea (I am not even sure whether this part is okay.) how to cluster them according to common trigrams. I tried to do with `itertools-combinations` but I got lost, and I didn't know how to generate multiple clusters, since the number of clusters can not be known without comparing each sentence with each other. The expected output is given below, thanks in advance for any help.

```
Cluster1: 'I would like to eat pizza with her.'
          'She would like to eat pizza with olive.'

Cluster2: 'There are some sentences must be clustered.' 
          'These sentences must be clustered according to common trigrams.'

Sentences do not belong to any cluster:                                
          'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
          'Apples are red, bananas are yellow.'
```

**EDIT:** I have tried with `combinations` one more time, but it didn't cluster at all, just returned the all sentence pairs. (obviously I did something wrong).

```
from itertools import combinations

new_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(sentence_tokens, mytrigrams)}

common=[] 
no_cluster=[]   
sentence_pairs=combinations(new_dict.keys(), 2)

for keys, values in new_dict.items():

    for values in sentence_pairs:
        sentence1= values[0]
        sentence2= values[1]
        #print(sentence1, sentence2)
        if len(set(sentence1) & set(sentence2))!=0:
            common.append((sentence1, sentence2))
        else:
            no_cluster.append((sentence1, sentence2))


print(common)
```

But even if this code worked it would not give the output I expect, as I don't know how to generate multiple clusters based on common n-grams

Answer (score 0):

To better understand your problem, you could explain the purpose and expected outcome.
Using Ngrams is something that must be done very carefully, when using ngrams, you increase the number of dimensions of your dataset.
I advise you to first use TD-IDF and only then if you have not reached the minimum hit rate, you go to n-grams.
If you can better explain your problem I can see if I can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you should have written it as comment. This is not an answer. I have already tried with TF-IDF way. That doesn't give what I want. And I want to learn how to do it if there is a way to do it. The question I wrote is, I think, well-described (expect my own code, since I could not write at all)